# Beginner in Pyserial, detect when lagging behind

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I'm using pyserial to read data sent from an arduino nano.

I need to read a lot of data **in real time**.

To read it, I use this code:

```
import threading
ser = serial.Serial('COM6', 250000, timeout=0)
def serial_stuff():
    global numb_0
    global numb_1
    global continuer
    while continuer:
        chaine=ser.readline()
        numb_0=[int(s) for s in chaine.split() if s.isdigit()]
        time.sleep(0.005)
        if len(numb_0)>0:
            print("got one")
            numb_1=numb_0
thread = threading.Thread(target = serial_stuff)  
thread.start()
while 1:
    if numb_1!=numb_archive:
        numb_archive=numb_0
        #Do stuff to process the data here
```

The amount of data coming is quite big. Sometimes, the python script start to read the serial data with more and more lag because the data are coming to fast.

How to detect that the system is starting to lag (how to detect that the serial buffer is increasing very fast) ? I want to detect it, so I can send a signal to the arduino in order to lower the "bandwidth" of sent data.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is a website where you post the code related to your question and receive help based on that. You did not give any processing code.

Comment: Since *Arduino* `serial` output buffer is quite small, it is likely that the data is accumulating within `pyserial` input buffer. Therefore you can use `ser.inWaiting()` to check how many bytes accumulated there. If you do it at constant time intervals you can determine whether it is the case to ask *Arduino* to slow down or, more simply, work harder to crunch the data using the full extent of your machine computational power.. which shouldn't be dwarfed by an *Arduino*.

Comment: I have added some more info  about my code. Could you explain me how to "work harder to crunch the data" ? thanks :)

Comment: @n0tis well, your computer has multiple cores, doesn't it? Thus, you could use threads. And you should profile your application to find out why is it so slow: are you reading one byte at a time? are you making lots of print calls to the terminal? do you have any other task going on that takes up a lot of time and should be put into a separate thread? Your CPU frequency is much higher than that of the Arduino, so there is no technical reason that should make you lag behind.. it's all in the design.

Answer (score 0):

The `serial.Serial` object has an `inWaiting()` method - it returns the number of bytes waiting in the serial buffer. You could use the value of this to decide when to throttle your Arduino.

Note that in PySerial 3.0, this has changed to `in_waiting()`, see the [documentation](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.in_waiting)